# Alternative to Align Environment For Specific Purpose

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

Consider the following code.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large
\textsf{CHEM 2410 $-$ Physical Chemistry II} \\
\textsf{Final Exam Review Notes} \\
\linethickness{1mm}
\textcolor{Zaffre}{\line(1,0){470}}
\end{center}
\large
\section*{Chapter 6}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Ivory,colframe=Zaffre!75!black, sharp corners]
    \textbf{Extent of Reaction} \hfill $d\xi=\displaystyle\frac{dn_A}{v_A}$
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Ivory,colframe=Zaffre!75!black, sharp corners]
    \textbf{Gibbs Reaction Energy} \hspace*{\fill}
        \begin{align*}
            \Delta_r G &= \left(\displaystyle\frac{\partial G}{\partial \xi} \right)_{p,T}\\
   \Delta_r G &= \mu_A - \mu_B\\
   \Delta_r G &= \Delta_r G^{\theta} + RT \ln Q
        \end{align*}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\Delta_r G < 0 \iff$ \textbf{exergonic} $\iff$ \textbf{forward spontaneous}
    \item $\Delta_r G > 0 \iff$ \textbf{endergonic} $\iff$ \textbf{reverse spontaneous}
    \item $\Delta_r G = 0 \iff$ \textbf{equilibrium}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

I want to make the Gibbs Reaction Equation box look like that of the Extent of Reaction equation box. The align environment adds vertical space and centers the equations, neither of which is wanted. I do, however, want the = signs aligned, but on the right. Are there any simple solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for `$\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}$`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,tcolorbox}

\colorlet{Ivory}{white!50!orange}% ...or whatever
\colorlet{Zaffre}{blue!75!white}% ...or whatever

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \large\sffamily
  CHEM 2410 $-$ Physical Chemistry II \\
  Final Exam Review Notes \\
  \linethickness{1mm}%
  \textcolor{Zaffre}{\line(1,0){470}}
\end{center}

\section*{Chapter 6}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Ivory,colframe=Zaffre!75!black, sharp corners]
  \textbf{Extent of Reaction} \hfill $d\xi = \dfrac{dn_A}{v_A}$
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=Ivory,colframe=Zaffre!75!black, sharp corners]
  \textbf{Gibbs Reaction Energy} \hfill
    $\begin{aligned}
      \Delta_r G &= \biggl( \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \xi} \biggr)_{p,T}\\
      \Delta_r G &= \mu_A - \mu_B\\
      \Delta_r G &= \Delta_r G^{\theta} + RT \ln Q
    \end{aligned}$
  \end{tcolorbox}
\begin{itemize}
  \item $\Delta_r G < 0 \iff \textbf{exergonic} \iff \textbf{forward spontaneous}$
  \item $\Delta_r G > 0 \iff \textbf{endergonic} \iff \textbf{reverse spontaneous}$
  \item $\Delta_r G = 0 \iff \textbf{equilibrium}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```